# Code stops unexpectedly instead of running infinitely

Tags: java

This is a classic queuing problem. Supposed to put a number and get the same number. This should continue forever.

My teacher used this problem to demonstrate the use of wait().
But I handled it differently.

```java
public class Q {
    int n;
    boolean Ready;
    public Q()
    {
        Ready = false;
    }
    public void setReady(boolean ready) {
        Ready = ready;
    }
    public boolean isReady() {
        return Ready;
    }
    synchronized void put(int n)
    {
        this.n = n;
        System.out.println("PUT:"+n);
    }
    synchronized int get()
    {
        System.out.println("GOT:"+n);
        return n;
    }
}

public class Producer extends Thread {

    Q q;

    public Producer(Q q) {
        super();
        this.q = q;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int i=0;
        for(;;)
        {
            if(!q.isReady())
            {
                q.put(i++);
                q.setReady(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer extends Thread {
    Q q;

    public Consumer(Q q) {
        super();
        this.q = q;
    }



    public void run()
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            if(q.isReady())
            {
                q.get();
                q.setReady(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in main, I link the same Q object to a consumer and a producer.
Then I start both the threads(Consumer object and Producer object).

The code stops after some numbers like 48,84 etc.
But I thought it should be an infinite loop.

Comment: Did he want to show you the "producer consumer" problem? Because you could experience a deadlock if it's not implemented correctly.

Comment: Probably you get an exception, show that exception or post the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It sounds like a deadlock issue, I'm not certain but I do not believe your run methods inside of producer consumer are thread-safe/atomic operations, which could cause issues. Just a guess though

Comment: @plum No, not a Deadlock. Because the methods of Consumer and Producer do not try to call each other.

Comment: FWIW, this is busy-waiting, never a good use of resources when it can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one problems in your code.

First of all even getter and setters are not thread-safe. 
In the body of your for loop in the run() of the producer

```
if(q.isReady())
            {
                q.get();
                q.setReady(false);
            }
...
```

q.isReady() and the body of the if might not be executed line after line.

- One issue might be that q.isReady() returns true for a first thread, then a second thread is getting the handle, is also executing q.isReady() and therefore the body of the if -> the q.setReqady(false) is executed.
- The first thread gets the handle back, also executed the q.get() and q.setReady(false) (as the thread returns where it was before) which is not expected.

There are two possible ways to fix that:

**1. synchronize the getter and setter**

```
public synchronized void setReady(boolean ready) {
        Ready = ready;
    }
    public synchronized boolean isReady() {
        return Ready;
    }
```

**2. synchronize the parts that need to be executed "atomically"**

- this method is more error prone as you have to synchronize the use of the methods from the outside. There might be more than one place where you execute the same methods - you have to synchronize them everywhere.
  You can do this by putting the chain of methods in a "synchronized(critical object) { ... } block. The "instance of the object" is locked for all threads until the body of the synchronized is completely executed.

**3. You execute the threads wrongly**

1. As you do not show your main method I have to imagine how you do it. 
   My suggestion is that you start multiple Consumers and Producers which will lead to a synchronization error.

If you only start one producer and one consumer...

2. You start the threads wrongly
   If your main method only look like this:

   ...
   consumer1.start();
   producer1.start();
   }

The issue here is that you do not wait on the threads to finish. Even though the threads should keep running your main thread stops his execution after starting the other threads.
The JVM will clean up the lost threads at some point (they will not run forever as you lost the referene to them).

Simply fix it by either calling consumer1.join() or procer1.join() (or both).

Comment: You're not wrong, but I think the OP only has one Producer and one Consumer.

Comment: @another-dave we do not know, but it is very unlikely as there is no way that the code will stop with only one consumer and producer.

Comment: He said: "I start both the threads(Consumer object and Producer object)."   Both = 2.  Object = singular.  But that's assuming the words actually mean what they say, always risky :-)   As for "no way", I agree I can't see any way either.

Comment: Though I am wondering if there's some visibility issue due to the poor sync.  Suppose 'ready' is set true but the change never becomes visible to the other processor, which is not in any synchronized section.  But I'll admit to being hazy on the interthread visibility rules.  If this were me, i'd put the 'ready' changes inside the get/put methods.

Comment: @another-dave I just came up with an idea and I am pretty sure thats correct. See my (3.).

Comment: @MarcoZielbauer Your '1' worked, but I didn't get the point. On the contrary I was pretty convinced that your '3' would work, but it didn't. For the record, I just used 1 consumer object and 1 producer object making it only two threads.